# Quirk of Kivy FloatLayout scaling? -- or am I missing something fundamental

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've had quite a few problem with the FloatLayout and scaling when working many widgets,
especially images. While I've gone through the documentation and much of the source code,
I suspect I'm missing something fundamental. To demonstrate, I've written a small
sample program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv_text = """
#:kivy 1.9.2-dev

GameScreen:

<GameScreen>
    Image:
        source: 'just_blue.png'
        size_hint: (1.0, 1.0)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0}
    Image:
        source: 'gimp_pine.png'
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0}
    Button:
        text: "0.5, 0.5"
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0}
"""

# notes:
# both PNG files are 400 x 400 pixels
# the resulting window created on my PC is 800 x 600

class GameScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class GameApp(App):

    def build(self):
        presentation = Builder.load_string(kv_text)
        return presentation

    def on_start(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GameApp()
    app.run()
```

And this results in this:

[image: screenshot]

I see two problems:

1. The lower left hand corners are not in the lower left of the window.
2. Clearly the sizes of the PNGs are also wrong. Only the button is correct.

The app that I'm working on cannot resort to a fancy 'background' workaround. I'd really like
to use widgets for the hundreds of items being manipulated.

For reference, here is the text log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/johnd/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-13_40.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-a97fe07, 20170413
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] Application requested a -dev version of Kivy. (You have 1.9.2.dev0, but the application requires 1.9.2-dev)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <NVIDIA Corporation>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.50 NVIDIA>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
(venv) johnd@johnd-GP60-2QF ~/Projects/test_kivy $ python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/johnd/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-13_41.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-a97fe07, 20170413
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] Application requested a -dev version of Kivy. (You have 1.9.2.dev0, but the application requires 1.9.2-dev)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <NVIDIA Corporation>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.50 NVIDIA>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

While I am running 1.9.2.dev0 of kivy with SDL2, but I've seen this same exact behavior in 1.9.1 and pygame.

(Adding to this, the scaling issue becomes much worse in an android environment. But I'll ask about that on a separate stack overflow.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but try setting `allow_stretch: True` and `keep_ratio: False` in your Images. This will let the image stretch to fill the widget, and make it clear where the Images actually are positioned.

Comment: That was it. I suspected it was something simple but not obvious. It is very non-intuitive because the opposite (shrinking) occurs automatically. So if an image is less than unity (<100%) it shrinks, but if over unity (>100%) you have to specifically declare `allow_stretch: True`. Or, to put it another way, you can't ignore resolution like 'relative positioning' implies.